# How to pass parameters in a url without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass different parameters on my webpage without page refresh. Is this possible by any means?

For example: 
My current webpage is "currentpage.php". After interact with some form elements -using jquery/ajax or any other- the url becomes "currentpage.php?x=foo&y=bar"

So that I can use `$_REQUEST['foo']` or `$_REQUEST['bar']` for some work on my currentpage.

Comment: That is not going to work. Even if you were able to change the URL to be `currentpage.php?x=foo&y=bar`, PHP will only do something when the page gets rendered.

Comment: The `$_REQUEST` array will be populated only when you render or load or refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do so, use sessions and store your variables in

```
$_SESSION['foo1']=$_REQUEST['foo'];
```

In this manner you may be able to save your data and then pass parameters using javascript with window.location.href or by submitting forms.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no page refresh, then no request to server. But behavior you are describing is similar to SPA. Sample [here](http://durandaljs.com/samples.html).